# Angular is it possible to access resolved data within route definition?

Tags: angular

I need to do some stuff within the route definition, when the lazyloaded module is loaded.
The route has a resolver UserDataResolverService, how can I access the resolved data within the route definition?

```
 {
        path: 'path-a',
        resolve: { userData: UserDataResolverService},
        loadChildren: () =>
            import('./pages/my.module').then((m) => {
                // access resolved data here: userdata.details
                return m.MyModule;
            }),
  }
```

Comment: In the lazy loaded module use the ActivatedRoute to get the data.

Comment: `loadChildren` should simply return a module. Why would you even want to add logic there?

Comment: I have a micro-fe architecture. That route loads the remote module and contextually I want to communicate to it some data emitting a CustomEvent @Pieterjan

Comment: Then either use a service to store the state, or handle the [`activate`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.component.html#L14) event. Don't add complex logic into the route module loader.

Comment: Note that your very advanced, complex, intensive logic will be called for all the routes when using [`PreloadAllModules`](https://angular.io/api/router/PreloadAllModules). Your code will result in a horrific UX in that case. (and obviously I strongly suggest you use `PreloadAllModules`...)

Comment: Also, it seems to me that you want to implement access control, but you want to do it at route-level. Don't. You can very easily do it using [route guards](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate), which is the recommended way to do. The method implemented can return an `Observable`, `Promise` or `boolean`. Angular supports all of that... ([example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/guards/is-in-role/is-in-role.guard.ts#L18))

Answer (score 1):

You can simply inject `ActivatedRoute` in your child component and then use

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.data['userData']);
}
```

Comment: I need to access data when the route is defined, not in the component

Comment: oh sorry, my bad. Why exactly do you need access there? Is this data used for specifying which modules to load?